# Efficient closure structure in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm starting to write a server in node.js and wondering whether or not I'm doing things the right way...

Basically my structure is like the following pseudocode:

```
function processStatus(file, data, status) {
...
}

function gotDBInfo(dbInfo) {
    var myFile = dbInfo.file;
    function gotFileInfo(fileInfo) {
        var contents = fileInfo.contents;
        function sentMessage(status) {
            processStatus(myFile, contents, status);
        }
        sendMessage(myFile.name + contents, sentMessage);
    }
    checkFile(myFile, gotFileInfo);
}
checkDB(query, gotDBInfo);
```

In general, I'm wondering if this is the right way to code for node.js, and more specifically:

1) Is the VM smart enough to run "concurrently" (i.e. switch contexts) between each callback to not get hung up with lots of connected clients?

2) When garbage collection is run, will it clear the memory completely if the last callback (processStatus) finished?

Answer (score 2):

1. Node.js is event-based, all codes are basically handlers of events. The V8 engine will execute-to-end any synchronous code in the handler and then process the next event.

   Async call (network/file IO) will post an event to another thread to do the blocking IO (that's in <strike>`libev`</strike> `libeio` AFAIK, I may be wrong on this). Your app can then handle other clients. When the IO task is done, an event is fired and your callback function is called upon.

   Here's an example of aync call flow, simulating a Node app handling a client request:

   ```
   onRequest(req, res) {
       // we have to do some IO and CPU intensive task before responding the client

       asyncCall(function callback1() {
           // callback1() trigger after asyncCall() done it's part
           // *note that some other code might have been executed in between*

           moreAsyncCall(function callback2(data) {
               // callback2() trigger after moreAsyncCall() done it's part
               // note that some other code might have been executed in between

               // res is in scope thanks to closure
               res.end(data);

               // callback2() returns here, Node can execute other code
               // the client should receive a response
               // the TCP connection may be kept alive though
           });

           // callback1() returns here, Node can execute other code
           // we could have done the processing of asyncCall() synchronously 
           // in callback1(), but that would block for too long 
           // so we used moreAsyncCall() to *yield to other code*
           // this is kind of like cooperative scheduling
       });

       // tasks are scheduled by calling asyncCall()
       // onRequest() returns here, Node can execute other code
   }
   ```
2. When V8 does not have enough memory, it will do garbage collection. It knows whether a chunk of memory is reachable by live JavaScript object. I'm not sure if it will aggressively clean up memory upon reaching end of function.

References:

[This Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9Jlu_h_Lyw) presentation discussed the GC mechanism of Chrome (hence V8).

http://platformjs.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/node-js-under-the-hood/

http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2011/04/10/NodeJS

Comment: For point #1- to clarify, does it matter if callbacks are nested or is that completely irrelevant?

For point #2, I meant for garbage collection- clarified that above, thanks

Comment: @davidkomer for #1 Yes and no. It only matters if they are nested if you need to enclose data (which you do in `gotFileInfo` by accessing `myFile` which was defined in the wrapping function. Your using the named method for defining functions and I can't say for sure if that works - if it does, and preserves scopes more power to you. I would highly recommend that you do nest callbacks with requirements on the outer function (making a closure) by defining anonymous functions: `var someFunk = function() { /* I have no name */ };` and then use `someFunk` to pass in your callback.

Comment: @davidkomer Frankly speaking, your sample code seems "too synchronous". You have to make the IO or processing async to fit the paradigm of Node.js.

Comment: @leesei Not sure what you mean by "seems." Can you please show how my sample code could possibly be more asynchronous?

Comment: Async code will either take a callback (see above) or return promise/deffered/future object for the caller to wait on or install callback. I didn't see those in your code so my guess was that the code is synchronous.

Comment: So your `got<*>` functions are callbacks? I have been mistaken then, sorry.